# Tensor product of sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, tensor-products

Does there exist an explaination of the product of 2 sigma-algebra in terms of of tensor product ? Which could explain the tensor product sign for the product of 2 sigma-algebra.

In particuliar, does there exists a good notion of bimorphism such that the product of 2 sigma-algebra is definied in terms of an universal property ?

Comment: Perhaps it comes from the notation $(f\otimes g)(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for (measurable) functions $f,g$ on $X$, resp. $Y$. As for continuous functions, the actual (algebraic) tensor product of vector spaces $\mathcal{C}^0(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{C}^0(Y,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in the space $\mathcal{C}^0(X\times Y)$ in the norm topology. So any $F(x,y)$ is approximated by $f_i(x)g_i(y)$.

Comment: As for measurable subsets of a given set $X$ (with respect to a given outer measure), I think the association $X\mapsto$ {measurable subsets of $X$} goes the other way around (opposite to the case of functions), more like the homology chains $X\mapsto C_{\cdot}(X)$ or just homology $X\mapsto H_{\cdot}(X)$ of a topological space. Now, for chains there is Eilenberg-Zilber theorem and for homology there is Kunneth, involving tensor product...

Comment: If it wasn't for the $\sigma$, but just an algebra, then yes, a set-algebra can, via indicator functions, be identified with an algebra over the field ${\mathbb F}_2$ of two elements and the corresponding tensor product is the product of the two algebras.